# Simplest way to login to Salesfoce API? Oauth?

Tags: oauth, salesforce

Forgive the complete newbie questions. I'm very new to the Salesforce API.

I'm attempting to connect to one specific account where I have the login/password info. This app will not be for public use. I've done a lot of research and it seems I do not need Oauth 2.0 and can instead use Oauth.

Well, there is a huge tangle of different identifiers needed to make this work including username, password, customer key, secret and token.

I created a test Connected App in order to obtain the customer key and secret and then attempted to curl directly from the shell like this (got example from https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/):

```
curl https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token  -d "grant_type=password" -d "customer_key" -d "client_secret=secret" -d "username=abc@def.com" -d "password=xxxxx"
```

but I get an error that

```
 {"error_description":"authentication failure","error":"invalid_grant"}
```

Is the token needed? I've seen some info that if the IP range is set and the connection is from that range then it should not be appended to the password.

All I want to do is connect to this account via the API so I can pull in data that will be used elsewhere. This seems needlessly complex and error-prone. How can I easily connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I use:

```
curl https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token \
  -d "grant_type=password" \
  -d "client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID" \
  -d "client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET" \
  -d "username=YOUR_USERNAME" \
  -d "password=YOUR_PASSWORD_AND_SECURITY_TOKEN"
```

Maybe you are forgetting to append your security token to the end of your password?

Comment: Thanks. I actually had a typo in the user name as well but the security token solved it.